# Log the page from where the clickout if coming using PHP

Tags: php

Currently I have a system within PHP where I track the click outs of a website. For these clicks I track various points of information which are available in the url and/or server (like IP address, date & time).

An example url is: /out/123/2/ where the 123 is the supplier ID and /2 tells me if the click out origin is coming from a newsletter (or other external, not my website related, page).

I want to also track the page from where the click out is coming from. I currently use  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the referrer page of the visitor, but currently this is not always filled when the visitor clicks the link. Some instances are blank/empty.

I’m looking for a solution that captures are ‘last’ pages when the visitor clicks on the click out, the above solution with the HTTP_REFERER is not working 100%. Alternative options I have been thinking about are:

- Use Sessions – Store the last page in the session and read from it when processing the click out.
- Use Cookies – same as sessions, but now with cookies

Both will work when the visitor is on the website, but when an visitor is not on the website I will get a blank outcome. This will not allow me to track the visitor where it came from, to improve the functionality.

What is the best practice to track all ‘last’ pages from the visitors on the website when they click the ‘click out’ url?

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is set by the client, so you can't rely on its presence and correctness. Sessions and Cookies won't work if one user opens multiple pages at the same time. You could encode the current location in your `out` URL as well and fall back to the referer if that's not possible for some reason.

Comment: @fab thanks for the suggestion. What would you suggest practically? /out/123/2/194 where 194 is the ID of the page? And what do you mean with the fallback to the referer? You mean when I cannot add a ID to the `out` url I should use the referer page?

Comment: yes, something like that (to both questions).

Comment: No Fancy solutions, no other solutions then sending the information along? Just because there many possible pages a use can come from.